# Countdown timer shows different remaining Time on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, php, datetime, time, countdown

I have a countdown-timer on my wordpress page, I use the countdown from the Ultimate Addon-Pack for Visual Composer.

At first it worked properly in Chrome but in Firefox only **NaN** was shown.

I did some research and found out, that I have to put a "T" between date and time >> "2016:05:22T20:00:00"

Then it worked properly in Firefox but in Chrome it shows 2 hours too much.

**Firefox:**

> 24 Days 07 Hours 01 Minute 11 Seconds

**Chrome:**

> 24 Days **09** Hours 01 Minute 11 Seconds

How can I fix this?

Comment: Not sure but timezone can be causing it. You can try using `date.toUTCString()` and then remove the offset value

Comment: Sorry but i am not an advanced user - where do i have to input this? i have a countdown.php file with all the code in it. thank you!

Comment: I have already set the time-zone to Europe, i don't think that the problem is the time zone. It's definitely the "T". Does Chrome handle this in an other way than Firefox? Without the "T" it works perfectly in Chrome. In Safari the same problem as in Chrome

Comment: The last exit in my opinion is to deliver different Countdowns to different browsers

Comment: I'm sure no browser(except safari on windows), will have special handling to date object. They have their implementations, but they will not add/subtract anything on their own, unless difference in Timezone. Also do share how you are using this date to display on view

Comment: From your problem description, it sounds like this was a simple issue of setting the initial Date value from which the script is supposed to count down from. Parsing date values using JavaScript’s `Date.parse` is a rather error-prone thing (http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+javascript+date+parsing). That being said, the use of `:` as separator between the date parts is rather unusual – try `2016-05-22T20:00:00` instead, that should work in both Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Is it an option to just use an existing Framework?

If yes, then just use Moment.js for this: http://momentjs.com/

or Bootstrap TimePicker: http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/

With these two Frameworks you can parse a time-string into a DateTime